# Can't resolve System.Drawing.Bitmap and System.Drawing.ImageConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

I have a line of code I borrowed from somewhere that Visual Studio can't resolve either the `Bitmap` or the `ImageConverter` class reference.

I have:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

the line of code is

```
Image x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(myImage.GetImage()));
```

If I look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx

I see both classes are in the namespace I'm using.  Is there something I am not doing correctly?  I have verified I am using .NET 4.5.

I have changed it to:

```
byte[] foo = new byte[256];
Image x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(foo));
```

and I still get the issue.

Comment: How can I tell if they are for WinForm or wpf?  All I want to do is take a byte array of a jpef and read it into an image.  I can't tell which classes I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reasons in my mind:

Did you add the referance ? that `using System.Drawing;` has give an error too, if you dont add it check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294670.aspx) and add this `using System.Drawing;` referance

There will be two namespaces that uses different Bitmap or Image classes. Try using `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

---

However, `System.Drawing.Image` and `System.Drawing.Bitmap` are WinForms and should usually not be used in WPF.

You should convert the byte array into a WPF [`ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx), e.g. to assign it to the `Source` property of an Image control.

You'll have to use the WPF [`ImageSourceConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class, not `ImageConverter`.

```
using System.Windows.Media;
...

byte[] foo = ...
var imageSource = (ImageSource)((new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFrom(foo));

image.Source = imageSource;
```

Comment: Your response solved this problem but now there is a conflict between images in System.Dawing and System.Windows.Controls.  I think I am mixing up winForms and wpf?  How do you know which to use?

Comment: System.Drawing has its own class with the same name. Just like i said, `System.Windows.Controls.Image` or `System.Drawing.Image` write like that, if you wanna use the element one. I don't know what your program has to do, so i can't just say "Use drawing one" or "Use Control one". But i think you need the control one.

`System.Windows.Controls.Image x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(myImage.GetImage()));`

Comment: Correct, I need the control version.  Thank you.  Now I need a better way to convert the image array to this format.

Comment: If you delete that `using System.Drawing;` line, then your image is not need that `System.Windows.Controls.Image` thing, just `Image` .

 But, your bitmaps and imageconverter (classes which System.Drawing has), Then you need to add them `System.Drawing` . Choose whatever you want.

I dont understand that image array thing, Can you explain a little bit if you need help with it too.

Comment: I should probably ask a different question.  I'm sure there are rules against this.  I have a byte array that is a jpeg from a camera.  I want to display it into a Systems.Windows.Control.Image.  I have looked at many ways in System.drawing.

Comment: Right. Then mark that post as answered and ask another. 
Besides, thanks for the warning

Comment: Don't use WinForms Bitmap at all.